# In network and settings wireless properties tab is missing

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

When i try to change wifi password of my pc i do not find wireless properties tab in right clicking the status of the network connection

Navigation : Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the wifi password to connect to a specific connection, or are you trying to change the password of a wifi connection itself? In my experience, I use the configuration options of the router to change the password, not anything windows offers. If you're trying to connect to a specific connection and need to change the password, you can always use windows options to forget the connection, then do a wifi scan to find it again and reinput the password.

Comment: Hi, Actually i want to change the password of wifi connection itself. Because by default my pc has a ascii key value which is very long to share with the other device when i try to connect to connect to a new device.

Comment: That works! You can usually do that from the router's browser interface. If you open a web browser on your system and go to address 192.168.1.1 you should be able to access these options, including changing the wifi password. You may need to enter the old password to actually enter the interface. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Stealth_kong when copied the address in the chrome i do not receive any data

Comment: What kind of router are you using? Depending on the router the access may be different. You can always check out the manufacturer's website if you don't have the manual. That should give you a little information on where to go to get to the interface.

Comment: I am not using any broadband connection. I simply want to access internet in pc via mobile by connecting through wifi instead of using a usb cable.As pc wifi is password protected it is difficult to type a defaullt ascii key of a specified network. Please help in this issue

Comment: It still sounds like you need to access the router itself to change the password. Windows networking will only allow you to enter the password of a network you're trying to connect to, but in order to change that password you need to access the router. Even if you're not using a wired connection you'll still need the password if you're attempting to access a connection through wifi.